# Trying to upload photo to flask server

Tags: android, cordova, flask

I am working on a project where I take a picture on my phone and upload to a server. I currently have the button working and it returns the location of the image. How or what should I add to get a base64 encoding or how should I proceed to upload it to flask. Thanks

```
    <div class="page">
        <p><img src="img/logo.png" alt="image" id="photo" /></p>
        <p><button id="btn">Take Picture</button></p>
        <p id="msg"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
        let app = {
            init: function(){
                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', app.takephoto);
            },
            takephoto: function(){
                let opts = {
                    quality: 80,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK,
                    targetWidth: 300,
                    targetHeight: 400
                };

                navigator.camera.getPicture(app.ftw, app.wtf, opts);
            },
            ftw: function(imgURI){
                document.getElementById('msg').textContent = imgURI;
                document.getElementById('photo').src = imgURI;

            },
            wtf: function(msg){
                document.getElementById('msg').textContent = msg;
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.init);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1) You want to allow you user to upload a file to flask. There is an in-built way to do this. However, personally I would recommend using [Flask-Uploads](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/). It's a Flask extension designed specifically for making this easy.

2) You'll want to convert your files into base-64. There is a built in module for this called [base64](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. I have changed the output from file into base64 so instead of FILE_URI it is now DATA_URL. Now the issue I'm stuck on is uploading to flask I dont know the code to upload it